# where to put a model's method?

Tags: ios, core-data

I'm new to Core Data so I thought I'd ask this here.

I have a model, User Recording, which, for now, has the following:

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSDate * dateCreated;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSData * audioData;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * name;
```

What I'd really like is to have a method in there, called "play", to play the recording.  Right now, I'm putting it in my view controllers but that's clearly bad because I've got that same method in two controllers. I've looked around a bit (and will keep looking) but can't figure it out - where should it go?  Should I have a model controller (manager)?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

your controller should have a hold to the model (that is, an instance variable or property), so that when the user clicks a button in the view (which should have an outlet to connect to the controller) you can invoke the message you want.

Just add the play method to your model (in the header file, so that is's public) and let the controller call that method when the user interacts with the view.

Comment: Yes my controller does have a hold to the model.. So it's ok to put non-accessor methods into a Core Data model?  I might be over thinking it but I wanted to check..

Comment: Nuts.. I implemented your suggestion but now I'm getting a "Symbol not found: ___CFObjCIsCollectable" error.  I've seen posts that it's a bug in the simulator but I didn't get that error before - it played correctly.